# Apache Mina Sshd Server Display and Change Root Directory

Tags: sshd, apache-mina

I am struggling with multiple Roots in Apache Mina. Using this constructor (it's marked private in the comment but is still public)

```
NativeFileSystemView(String userName, Map<String, String> roots, String current, char separator, boolean caseInsensitive)
```

allows to pass different "virtual name" and "physical directory" mappings. This works for the current directory (parameter "current") but unfortunately I do not find a way to "switch" between different roots nor is the "virtual name" displayed as "directory". Any hint how to use the root map correctly is appreciated.